# JSONModel with Objective C Tutorials

Tags: objective-c, jsonmodel

I am a newbie to Objective C. I want to know

1) Is there best Objective C tutorials for beginners?

and I have to do project that interacts with ASP.Net backend server. So

2) Is there any good tutorials or video lectures for using JSONModel with Objective C?

Help me please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [AppCoda](http://www.appcoda.com/), or [raywenderlich](http://raywenderlich.com). For more specific to your question, here is a good tutorial: [jsonMobil and Objective-c](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-jsonmodel--cms-19840)

If you really want to learn and understand `Objective c`, then you should definitely get the [big nerd ranch book](https://www.bignerdranch.com/we-write/objective-c-programming/). It's really helpful.

After you finish that book, or once you have a base understanding of `Objective-c`, then have a look at this video: [Stanford - ios 7](https://itunes.apple.com/mg/course/developing-ios-7-apps-for/id733644550), or for the newer apple language - swift, watch this: [stanford - ios 8](https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-8-apps-swift/id961180099)

These types of questions shouldn't be asked on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). You can try a site like [Quora](http://www.quora.com/). They probably already have an answer for this.

Comment: Glad I was able to help! :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There are links to three tutorials on the JSONModel repo README here:
https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel#online-tutorials

The 2 part tutorial on tuts+ is good: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-jsonmodel--cms-19840

There aren't any JSONModel tutorials on raywenderlich.com

Please note that you need to know about Objective-C to use JSONModel so please first learn Objective-C

Comment: Thanks for your suggession , Marin. :D. I read and tested code from Tuts+. The URL to access JSON data is not working.

Comment: send them feedback :) they should check if the file has gone missing

Comment: Someone already sent feedback since 7 months ago. I will send them again too :)